Swap from Uniswap router
How to pass theese values our execute function - "Function: execute(bytes commands,bytes[] inputs,uint256 deadline)"

Have you already read the docs https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/universal-router/technical-reference ? You can also see the tests for some examples here https://github.com/Uniswap/universal-router/blob/main/test/integration-tests/Uniswap.test.ts

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/165723/how-to-swap-a-token-on-uniswapv3-in-python/165737#165737 - https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/tree/main/uni_router
